# ASP.NET web service timeout

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a ASP.NET asmx web service which times out.

I see that IIS has couple of places where the timeout setting can be defined.

I also know that the timeout setting can be defined in the web.config file using the "httpRuntime" element.

I also see that the app pool the service runs under has its own timeout setting

I am not sure why Microsoft has chosen to have timeouts at multiple levels even though they would end up affecting the web service as a whole. (other than in case of the app pool, where multiple applications can be run under)

Can someone please help me understand which one has precedence?

Answer (score 0):

on the service server side, try setting this in config:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200"/>
```